# securing REST endpoints with HTTP Digest authentication

Tags: python, security, rest, authentication, flask

- I am developing a project in `Python` using `Flask` which will have endpoints as

> ```
> @app.route(/transaction)
> def get(request):
>   ...
>
> @app.route(/transaction)
> def post(request):
>   ...
> ```

- Also, I would want that the REST endpoints are authenticated before they method executes
- I searched a lot about this and found that [Digest Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) is what I might need(I am not sure till now)

**Question**

- How can I implement such a security pattern using python and flask? any examples available that I can see and learn from it?
- I would like not to pass passwords in plaintext and using tokens is a much better idea, so does considering HTTP digest authentication is a right choice?
- anything else that you people may want to recommend?

I want my server to be **stateless** and not store any session on server side

Comment: What do you mean by `stateless server`? If you want to use authentication, then obviously you have to store credentials somewhere on the server side. In that sense session is just another layer of credentials. And indeed, with HTTP it is a bit hard (if possible) to have a stateful server.

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/.

For security exist extensions: http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Login/ and http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Principal/.

Stateless service doesn't store session data it mean that you must sent credentials for every request.

1. You can use just plain login and password or use hash functions for this.
2. You can store secret key on user side and generate/encrypt your plain data as login, password, another request data. This can protect you from another requests, but don't protect from some requests, but you also can add something like timestamp and reject any old requests or add unique request id and reject some requests.
3. You can use something more effective like https.

Stateful service also can get plain login and password for authentication and generate token for authorization, that send with every request.